# How to change mouse over effect to move up and fadein when moues in , and move down and fade out when out mouse?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to change mouse over effect to move up and fadein when moues in , and move down and fade out when out mouse ?

....................................................................................................................................................................

and it's not work on ie7 , how to solve that ?

http://jsfiddle.net/peap/rhmj0808/

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function(){
     $('#menu').hover(over, out);
   });

    function over(event)
    {
                console.log(!$("#mask").is(":animated"));
        if(!$("#mask").is(":animated")){
         $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
         $('#mask').css("display","block");
        }
    }

    function out(event)
    {
        console.log(!$("#mask").is(":animated"));
       if(!$("#mask").is(":animated")){
         $('#mask').fadeOut(1000);
       }
    } 
</script>

<style type="text/css">
#mask {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    z-index:0;
    display: none;
}

#menu{
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
}
</style>





<div id="mask">
    show hover
</div>

<img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1ead17c7ff6482d20e262c5c60c8fd1f?s=24&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" id="menu" style=" margin-left: 28px; height: 62px;"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use `animate`

```
$('#mask').stop().animate({'opacity':1}, 1000)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Biesas/rhmj0808/1/)

Comment: thank now ie ok,  and can i fadein , move up when mouse in and fadeout , move down when mouse out